# Nginx check if parameters exists and if so only allow specific values

Tags: nginx, regex

I cant seem to find a way to limit some queries. Right now i have this

```
if ($args ~* "(.*&)?page="){
   set $wrongP W;
}
if ($args !~* (.*&)?page=(2|12|24)$){
   set $wrongP "${wrongP}R";
}
if ($wrongP = WR){
   rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? permanent;
}
```

This does exactly what i want, the problem is if url has more than one parameter fox ex. /somefile.html?page=2&arg=file it removes ALL parameters. Im guessing its because of the second if.

How do check for urls that have multiple variables and removes all of them only if page variable is not equal to 2, 14 or 24 ?

Comment: There is no easy way to change only one parameter. May be you could use [Lua](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/) or [njs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/)

Comment: I dont want to change one paramter. I want to remove them all which is what rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? permanent; does. But only if parameter page exists and its not equal to 2, 12 or 24

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need something like this (using `map`):

```
map $arg_page $need_redirect {
  default "1";
  ""      "0";
  "2"     "0";
  "14"    "0";
  "24"    "0";
}

server {
  ...
  if ($need_redirect) {
    rewrite ^ $uri? permanent;
  }
  ...
}
```